# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, poo

Tengo un gran inconveniente al momento de desplegar un proyecto en el servidor(ubuntu 18.04, apache2 -PHP | mysql -phpmyadmin). Lo que sucede es que no me funciona los modelos en el server pero en local todo va muy bien, al recibir los datos en el servidor formData me genera ese este error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
> (Internal Server Error)

a continuación mi código, muchas gracias al que me pueda ayudar. Utilizo Ajax y sweetAlert2.
Recibo los datos con javascript, los envío al controlador con ajax, del controlador lo envío al modelo para consultar si existe un registro con ese correo, si existe devuelve existe, si no existe devuelve insertar, retorno los datos al controlador y a su vez el controlador envia la respuesta al ajax (formData) y si todo sale bien pues muestro la respuesta con seetAlert.

-funciones.js

```js
//Registrarse  
const formReg = document.querySelector("#formReg");
    formReg.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let btn = document.getElementById('register').innerHTML = "Validando Datos...";
        let strNombre = document.querySelector('#txtName').value;
        let strApellido = document.querySelector('#txtLastname').value;
        let strCorreo = document.querySelector('#txtEmail').value;
        let strPassword = document.querySelector('#txtPassword').value;
        let strCpassword = document.querySelector('#txtCpassword').value;

        if (strNombre == '' || strApellido == '' || strCorreo == '' || strPassword == '' || strCpassword == '') {

            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'warning',
              title: 'Atención',
              text: 'Todos los campos son requeridos',
              
            });
            let btn = document.getElementById('register').innerHTML = "Registrarse";
            return false;
        }else{
            var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXobjet('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            var ajaxUrl = base_url+'register/regUser';
            var formData = new FormData(formReg);
            request.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
            request.send(formData);
            request.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (request.status == 200 && request.readyState == 4){
                    var objData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    if (objData.status) {
                        Swal.fire({
                          icon: 'success',
                          title: 'Registro efectivo',
                          text: objData.msg
                        
                        });
                        let btn = document.getElementById('register').innerHTML = "Registrarse";
                    }else{
                        Swal.fire({
                          icon: 'warning',
                          title: 'Atención',
                          text: objData.msg
                          
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    });
```

-Controlador.php

```
<?php


Class register extends controllers{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();

        session_start();

        if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
             header("Location:".base_url());
        }
    }

    public function register($params)
    {   
        $data['id_page'] = 5;
        $data['tag_page'] = "Crear una cuenta";
        $data['title_page'] = "Crea una cuenta";
        $data['name_page'] = "Registro de usuaros";
        $data['page_functions_js'] = "functions_register.js";
        $this->views->getView($this,"register", $data);
    }

    public function regUser()
    {
        if ($_POST) {
            $nombre = strClean($_POST['txtName']);
            $apellido = strClean($_POST['txtLastname']);
            $email = strClean($_POST['txtEmail']);
            $contrasena = strClean($_POST['txtPassword']);
            $ccontrasena = strClean($_POST['txtCpassword']);

            $consultar = $this->model->searchUser($email);
            
            if ($consultar == 'insertar') {
                $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Registro el nuevo user');
            }elseif($consultar == 'existe') {
                $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'ya existe ese correo');
            }else{
                $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'No se puedo insertar');
            }
            echo json_encode($arrResponse, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            die();
        }
        
    }

    public function confirm($params)
    {   
        if (empty($params)) {
            header("location:".base_url());
        }else{

            $idEncrypt = strClean($params);
            $idMail = seD:: decryption($idEncrypt);

        $data['id_page'] = 6;
        $data['tag_page'] = "Confirma tu cuenta";
        $data['title_page'] = "Confirma tu cuenta";
        $data['name_page'] = "Confirmar registro";
        $data['confirm'] = $this->model->setConfirmUser($idMail);
        $data['page_functions_js'] = "functions_confirm.js";
        $this->views->getView($this,"confirm", $data);
        }
    }


}// End Class register
```

?>

-Modelo.php

```
public function searchUser(string $email)
    {
        $return = "";
        $this->strCorreo = $emal;
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$this->strCorreo}' ";
        $request = $this->select_All($sql);
        if (empty($request)) {
            $return = "insertar";
        }else{
            $return = "existe";
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

-Mysql Consultar.php

```
//Devuelve todos los registros
        public function select_All(string $query)

        {
            $this->strquery = $query;
            $result = $this->conexion->prepare($this->strquery);
            $result->execute();
            $data = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $data;
        }
```

-Los 2 archivos del Error
Load.php

```
<?php


$controllerFile = "controllers/".$controller.".php";
if (file_exists($controllerFile)) 
{
    require_once($controllerFile);
    $controller = new $controller();

    if (method_exists($controller, $method)) {
        $controller ->{$method}($params);
    }else{
        require_once("controllers/error.php");
    }

}else{
    require_once("controllers/error.php");
}
```

-Index.php

```
<?php

require_once ("config/config.php");
require_once ("helpers/helpers.php");

$url = !empty($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'home/home';
$arrUrl = explode("/", $url);
$controller = $arrUrl[0];
$method = $arrUrl[0];
$params = "";

if (!empty($arrUrl[1])) 
{
    if ($arrUrl[1] != "")
    {
        $method = $arrUrl[1];
    }

}

if (!empty($arrUrl[2])) 
{
    if ($arrUrl[2] != "") {
        for ($i=2; $i < count($arrUrl); $i++) { 
            $params .= $arrUrl[$i]. ',';
        }
        $params = trim($params, ',');
    }
}

require_once("libraries/core/autoload.php");
require_once("libraries/core/load.php");
```

-Controller.php

```
<?php


    class controllers
    {
         public function __construct()
         {
            $this->views = new views();
            $this->loadModel();
         }

         public function loadModel()
         {
            //HomeModel
            $model = get_class($this)."model";
            $routClass = "models/".$model.".php";
            if (file_exists($routClass)) {
                require_once($routClass);
                $this->model = new $model();
            }
         }

    }// End class

?>


Agradezco mucho quien me pueda ayudar muchas gracias!
```

Comment: Hola amigo, @BetaM es la siguiente genera 2 errores: [Tue Feb 09 04:44:51.863001 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 9280] [client 181.136.46.122:52184] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: register::$model in /var/www/html/qa/controllers/register.php on line 55, referer: http://18.221.179.131/qa/register

Comment: Este es el segundo @BetaM [Tue Feb 09 04:44:51.863065 2021] [php7:error] [pid 9280] [client 181.136.46.122:52184] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function searchUser() on null in /var/www/html/qa/controllers/register.php:55\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/qa/libraries/core/load.php(11): register->regUser('')\n#1 /var/www/html/qa/index.php(32): require_once('/var/www/html/q...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/qa/controllers/register.php on line 55, referer: http://18.221.179.131/qa/register

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega completo el código de los 2 archivos que se señalan en el error

Comment: @BetaM Listo amigo en el Controlador Core, ahí te lo acabo de publicar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error base es la forma en la que tratas de acceder a las propiedades en clases que están heredando de otras.

Este mensaje de error:

> PHP Notice: Undefined property: register::$model in

En tu clase `register` se debe a que dicha propiedad precisamente no esta definida y de hecho estás tratando de usarla para darle como valor la instancia de una clase.

Precisamente por lo anterior se genera tu segundo error el cual dice:

> Call to a member function searchUser() on null

Ya que no estás logrando obtener la instancia en dicha propiedad y a algo que es *NULL* no te va a permitir acceder a un método o propiedad x.

Dicho lo anterior, entonces debe alcanzar con definir a dicha propiedad dentro de la clase padre de esta forma:

```
class Controllers
{
    public object $model;
    
    /*
        Resto de tu código
    */
}
```

Entonces una vez definida, si puedes usarla dentro del método `loadModel` y asignarle un valor:

```
/*
    Resto de tu código
*/
public function loadModel(): void
{
    //HomeModel
    $model = get_class($this)."model";
    $routClass = "models/".$model.".php";
    if (file_exists($routClass)) {
        require_once($routClass);
        $this->model = new $model();
    }
}
/*
    Resto de tu código
*/
```

Comentarios finales:

- Estos cambios deberían lograr subsanar los errores que expones en los comentarios de tu pregunta
- Trata de seguir alguna guía de estilos para acrecentar la legibilidad de tu código, aqui te dejo:

  - [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#3-namespace-and-class-names)
  - [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/)
- Si usas alguna versión reciente de PHP, puedes aprovechar beneficios tales como:

  - [Propiedades tipadas en PHP 7.4](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.typed-properties)
  - [Declaraciones de tipo de devolución desde PHP 7](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations)
- Si tu versión de PHP no soporta las propiedades tipadas, entonces solo elimina el `object` de la propiedad que puse de ejemplo

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias!!! <3